# transmission-daemon, download complete shell script - raspberry pi

Tags: sudo, transmission-daemon

permissions of the script is fine and the script runs fine

however, if I run 'sudo' i get the following

`sudo: The "no new privileges" flag is set, which prevents sudo from running as root. sudo: If sudo is running in a container, you may need to adjust the container configuration to disable the flag.`

the user i am running transmission-daemon as,

has permissions to run sudo,

how can i allow transmission-daemon to run the same commands ,

via download complete script,

that i can usually run as a user.

my use case is to restart vpn after download completes.

tried

running transmission-daemon as root,

it works,

but it fails to read the profile created by the user

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution, was quite simple actually, sharing in case anyone stumbles upon this

in the service that runs transmission-daemon

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/transmission-daemon.service
```

change `NoNewPrivileges=true` to `NoNewPrivileges=false`

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s STOP $MAINPID
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
NoNewPrivileges=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

that's the flag that needs to be changed